# Vue resets INPUT field when setting it to disabled

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Why does Vue reset a text input field when setting it to disabled? This doesn't happen with plain Javascript, and doesn't happen with a textarea.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '.container',
  data: {
   disabled: false,
   fn: "John",
   ln: "Smith",
   com: "My comment here..."
  },
  methods: {
   vue_disable() {
    this.disabled = !this.disabled;
   } 
  }
});

function js_disable() {
  document.getElementById("first_name").disabled = !document.getElementById("first_name").disabled;
  document.getElementById("comment").disabled = !document.getElementById("comment").disabled;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <h1>Vue disable fields</h1>
  
  <p>22 Aug 2019</p>
  
  <p>Why does an INPUT text field reset when I set the field to disabled with Vue? It doesn't happen with pure Javascript, and doesn't happen with a TEXTAREA.</p>
  
  <p>Type something new into the the First Name field then click the first button. The value you entered disappears and the original value is substituted.<p>

<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>First Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" :disabled="disabled" :value="fn"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Last name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" :value="ln"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Comment</label>
    <textarea rows="4" class="form-control" id="comment" v-html="com" :disabled="disabled">

      </textarea>
  </div>
  <p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" @click="vue_disable">Disable / Enable 'First Name' and 'Comment' fields with Vue</button>
  </p>
</form>
    <p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="js_disable()">Disable / Enable 'First Name' and 'Comment' fields with Javascript</button>
  </p>

</div>
```

https://codepen.io/MSCAU/pen/jONVRRj

Comment: My guesses is that vue is re-rendering the input field when you toggle the disabled, hence re-setting the initial value, since it is not a v-model and cannot change

Comment: Yes but odd that textarea is not similarly affected!

Answer (score 3):

Use `v-model` instead of `:value`

From the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html):

> Use the `v-model` directive to create two-way data bindings on form input, textarea, and select elements.

`value` attribute just sets the initial value for the input.

Vue adds getter/setters using `Object.defineProperty` to all the properties inside `data`. When a dependency’s `setter` is triggered, it notifies the watcher, and re-renders the component ([documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#How-Changes-Are-Tracked)). Since you changed `disabled` property, entire component re-rendered and `value` is set to the whatever is in `data`

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '.container',
  data: {
    disabled: false,
    fn: "John",
    ln: "Smith",
    com: "My comment here..."
  },
  methods: {
    vue_disable() {
      this.disabled = !this.disabled;
    }
  }
});

function js_disable() {
  document.getElementById("first_name").disabled = !document.getElementById("first_name").disabled;
  document.getElementById("comment").disabled = !document.getElementById("comment").disabled;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
    <p>
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>First Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" :disabled="disabled" v-model="fn" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Last name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" v-model="ln" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Comment</label>
          <textarea rows="4" class="form-control" id="comment" v-html="com" :disabled="disabled">
      </textarea>
        </div>
        <p>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" @click="vue_disable">Disable / Enable 'First Name' and 'Comment' fields with Vue</button>
        </p>
      </form>
      <p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="js_disable()">Disable / Enable 'First Name' and 'Comment' fields with Javascript</button>
      </p>

</div>
```

Comment: ye ye, this solves the issue, but **why** does it happen though? That's the interesting part.

Comment: @SølveTornøe I have already mentioned that. *"value attribute just sets the initial value for the input*"

Comment: Yes, but this is not the issue if i'm not mistaken. The issue as of what I understood is that when he toggles the disabled on the input field, the input gets its original data, like the input is re-rendered

Comment: Thanks, guys. I'm avoiding v-model because I don't want two-way data binding. In my real-life code, the initial value is a value deep in a JS object tree. I want to allow the user to change the data and then (if she chooses to do so) set the record to "read only" (ie. disabled), and then save the record (at which point, if the data is validated, I update the original value in the tree). I can see that I could get it to work with v-modal but I'd have to write extra code to duplicate the data before binding the duplicate to the form, and do the reverse on submit. It's not elegant.

Comment: I have submitted this as a bug to the Vue team: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/10422. In the meantime I've hacked around the issue with jQuery.